# How to output data to GUI textbox using workflow/parallel?

Tags: winforms, powershell, user-interface, parallel-processing, workflow

I am trying to output the result of the ping command to a textbox (windows forms GUI) using workflow/parallel and the message appears
"This type of assignment is not supported. Only variable names (i.e.: $variable) may be used as the target of an assignment statement."
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWtM8.png)
How can this issue be resolved?

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

workflow parallelPing {

    parallel {
        $text1_box.Text = ping "google.com"
        $text2_box.Text = ping  "8.8.8.8"
        $text3_box.Text = ping "stackoverflow.com" 
    }
}

$gui1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$gui1.Width = 1000
$gui1.Height = 700
$gui1.AutoSize = $false

$text1_box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$text1_box.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$text1_box.Multiline = $true
$text1_box.Width = 540
$text1_box.Height = 100
$gui1.Controls.Add($text1_box)

$text2_box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$text2_box.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,130)
$text2_box.Multiline = $true
$text2_box.Width = 540
$text2_box.Height = 100
$gui1.Controls.Add($text2_box)

$text3_box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$text3_box.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,240)
$text3_box.Multiline = $true
$text3_box.Width = 540
$text3_box.Height = 100
$gui1.Controls.Add($text3_box)

$getPing = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$getPing.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(560,110)
$getPing.Width = 170
$getPing.Height = 90
$getPing.Text = '&Ping'
$getPing.Add_Click({parallelPing})
$gui1.Controls.Add($getPing)

$gui1.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to assign the variable in the parallel block, use $workflow to access the workflow scope.

```
$workflow:Text1_box.text =
```

See [this link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-workflows-restrictions/) for more details.

Comment: Perhaps mark the answer? It seems the suggestion to use the workflow scope modifier is what helped resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
$getPing = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$getPing.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(560,110)
$getPing.Width = 170
$getPing.Height = 90
$getPing.Text = '&Ping'
$getPing.Add_Click({pingInfo})
$gui1.Controls.Add($getPing)

workflow parallelPing {

    parallel {
        $workflow:a1 = ping "google.com"
        $workflow:a2 = ping  "8.8.8.8"
        $workflow:a3 = ping "stackoverflow.com" 
    }
    $pingResult = @($a1, $a2, $a3)
    return $pingResult
}

function pingInfo{
    $text1_box.Lines = (parallelPing)[0]
    $text2_box.Lines = (parallelPing)[1]
    $text3_box.Lines = (parallelPing)[2]
}

$gui1.ShowDialog()
```

Thanks!